# Nginx subomdain always redirect to specific folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns

I've got a shopify website called https://mydomain-com.

This website has 3 subdomains, that are pointing to another server ip (A- record). On my server I've got 1 main root folder. How can I make sure all 3 subdomains are pointing to that root folder?

Because right now it's looking for the subdomain folder. I can't point my root domain ip to the server because it's a shopify website.

How can I make sure the subdomains are pointing to that 1 folder on my nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create configs for each subdomain. And specify root directory for those subdomains. Example:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name subdomain1.domain.com;

   root /path/to/directory;
   index index.html;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name subdomain2.domain.com;

   root /path/to/directory;
   index index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this in NGINX configuration file in your server

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  root /path/to/directory;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

However if you want to have different subdomains point to different folders, you can change the `server_name` value to the SUBDOMAIN-NAME as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain1.domain.com;

  root /path/to/directory1;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain2.domain.com;

  root /path/to/directory2;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain3.domain.com;

  root /path/to/directory3;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```